# How to remove HTML from Youtube when the page loads

Tags: html, jquery, youtube

Youtube has just added Tiktok-style 'shorts' which are addictive and useless videos that scroll endlessly.

I'd like to remove the HTML element that contains the reels automatically every time that I load youtube.com . Any ideas?

This is the element I'd like to remove every time I load the page:

```
<ytd-rich-section-renderer class="style-scope ytd-rich-grid-renderer" mini-mode="">
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is NOT a code writing service. If you have some code to do this that is not working and you need help you can then ask it here but don't ask us to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a script with this browser extension https://www.tampermonkey.net/

Hope you find it useful!